# python code doesn't iterate through whole loop and stuck at raw_input

Tags: python, terminal

I'm currently attempting to learn python and have recently purchased a book of beginner exercises etc. One of the challenges is to build a rock, paper, scissors game using the below code. When I use this code though, I get stuck in the move function, in terminal I enter a move and it doesn't move to the 'try' command and just prompts me to enter another number. It looks as though the program is stuck in the while loop and won't move further than raw_input. I've tried a few things but I can't seem to get my head around it. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

```
import random
import time

rock = 1
paper = 2
scissors = 3

names = {rock: "Rock", paper:"Paper", scissors:"Scissors"}
rules = {rock:scissors, paper:rock, scissors:paper}

player_score = 0
computer_score = 0

def start():
    print
    print "Let's play Rock, Paper, Scissors"
    while game():
        pass
    scores()

def game():
    player = move()
    computer = random.randint(1, 3)
    result(player, computer)
    return play_again()

def move():
    while True:
        print
        player = input("Rock = 1\nPaper = 2\nScissors = 3\nMake a Move: ")
        try:
            player = int(player)
            if player in (1,2,3):
                return player
        except ValueError:
            pass
        print "Oops! I didn't understand that. Please enter 1, 2, or 3"

def result(player, computer):
    print "1..."
    time.sleep(1)
    print "2..."
    time.sleep(1)
    print"3!"
    time.sleep(0.5)
    print "Computer threw {0}!".format(names[computer])
    global player_score, computer_score
    if player == computer:
        print"Tie Game."
    else:
        if rules[player] == computer:
            print "Your victory has been assured!"
            player_score += 1
        else: 
            print "The computer is victorious"
            computer_score += 1

def play_again():
    answer = raw_input("Would you like to play again? y/n")
    if answer in ("y", "yes", "Y", "Yes"):
        return answer
    else: 
        print "Thank you for playing!"

def scores():
    global player_score, computer_score
    print "HIGH SCORES"
    print "Player: ", player_score
    print "Computer: ", computer_score
```

Update: Seems that people in the comments can run the code fine, but when I run it through terminal I keep getting [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mxSTX.png). I've now run the same code through my housemates MacBook and the same problem persists.

Comment: you made a typo in function `game()` result _s_

Comment: Fixed the typo in the game() function and have changed raw_input to input to ensure the data type is int. However the loop still won't fully iterate and now when I enter a string, instead of the error message, terminal ends the program. Any ideas about where I'm going wrong?

Comment: Can you update the code in the question to the current code you're working with? Version in question still has type on result() in the game() function. Fixing that, the current code runs fine for me.

Comment: Updated the code. Tried to run in both terminal and IDLE and still not working? I've tried both raw_input and input.

Comment: Your `move` function works just fine for me (with either `input` or `raw_input`, though the latter is better at handling inappropriate entries). Are you pressing enter after typing in your text?

Comment: @Blckknght I'm entering an input and then pressing enter yes, when I do this, it just prompts me again to 'Make a move:'?

Comment: Maybe try adding 
`except ValueError as e:
print e`
To see if it's hitting some sort of exception?
Or to see what input you're actually getting:
`if player in (1,2,3):
  return player
else:
  print player`

Comment: When I run the code you've shown, it works as expected. So clearly something is going on in your environment that's not replicated in the code you've shown. I'd double check that you're actually running this code (and not some old version of it), and perhaps (as Robert Kelly suggests) modify the `try` block so that you'll see if you're getting an unexpected exception.

Comment: Can you try using `for player in [1,2,3]`?